# What's the bandwidth and form factor for PCIe x1 x4 x8 and x16?

Tags: hardware, pci-express

What speed, number of pins (physical size) are PCIe x1 x4 x8 and x16?

Normally I would google to find a photo showing the various types of PCI Express cards and their max bandwidth. Now that serverfault exists, I thought I'd lazily check if anyone here already has a good ***concise*** photo they could post as an answer.

EDIT: Thanks, vartec. I also found a nice diagram via Google:

[image: diagram]

Comment: But the diagram is now 404.

Comment: @Ruslan: fixed, I fetched a copy using Wayback Machine

Comment: I don't see how it's fixed. You haven't edited the post since May 23 '09. OK, I've found [the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120403165411/https://www.naplestech.com/shopcart/images/pcie_slots400.gif) myself.

Comment: @Ruslan Amro edited the post, but his edit needs to be approved and thus hasn't taken effect yet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Bandwidth:

legacy   PCIe 1.x - **250MB/s** per lane (16x == 16 lanes)
current  PCIe 2.0 - **500MB/s** per lane (thus 16x PCIe 2.0 is 8GB/s)
 
upcoming PCIe 3.0 - **1 GB/s** per lane

### Physical size ([from Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pci-e)):

> The width of a PCIe connector is 8.8
>   mm, while the height is 11.25 mm, and
>   the length is variable. The 'minor'
>   half of the connector is 11.65 mm in
>   length and contains 22 pins, while the
>   length of the 'major' half is
>   variable. The thickness of the card
>   going into the connector is 1.8 mm.

```
Lanes | Pins Total | Pins in 'major' half | Total Length | Length of 'major' half 
------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-----------------------
x1    |  36        |  14                  | 25 mm        |  7.65 mm 
x4    |  64        |  42                  | 39 mm        | 21.65 mm 
x8    |  98        |  76                  | 56 mm        | 38.65 mm 
x16   | 164        | 142                  | 89 mm        | 71.65 mm
```